# Shell Script (Bash) to sum multiples of different arguments below a number

Tags: beginner, bash, shell

I'm interested in learning how to create shell scripts with bash so here's one of my first exercises, taken from [here](https://goo.gl/QZSmNw). It is an extension of the problems Elementary - 4 and 5.

The goal of the program is to sum all multiples or ARG1 or ARG2 below the user's input number.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This program will find all the multiples of ARG1 or ARG2 below or equal to your number and sum them up. Please input your limit:"
read limit

commonMultiple=`expr $1 \* $2`

sumArg1=0
sumArg2=0
sumCommonMultiple=0

for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$1 )); do
    sumArg1=`expr $sumArg1 + $i`
done
for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$2 )); do
    sumArg2=`expr $sumArg2 + $i`
done
for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$commonMultiple )); do
    sumCommonMultiple=`expr $sumCommonMultiple + $i`
done

echo "The result is `expr $sumArg1 + $sumArg2 - $sumCommonMultiple`."
```

This works perfectly but I'd like the input of more experienced programmers. I don't think my logic is efficient. There must be something obvious I'm missing that could have made my code a lot simpler.

**Disclaimer:** apparently some of the stuff I used is outdated. I'll take it into account for my future code.*

Comment: You may find http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/135943 interesting.  The question isn't relevant, but the answer is—it's a a fascinating discussion of the actual purpose of shell scripting.  i.e. "What is bash actually for?"  (Written by the person who discovered the shell-shock bug, by the way.)  `bash` really isn't designed for computational/algorithmic problems at all.  It is a tool for specific types of jobs (see link) and in that domain it excels.

Comment: That's interesting!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Arithmetic operations

If you look closely, something is a bit odd here:

> ```
> for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$1 )); do
> ```

Ideas? How about: `i` is written without a dollar, but `limit` is written with a dollar... In fact you can drop the dollar from limit too, and the expression will be slightly simpler. From `$1` you cannot drop it, as the meaning of 1 would be taken literally, because it's numeric, unlike the others.

The same is true for `commonMultiple` here, you can drop the dollar:

> ```
> for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$commonMultiple )); do
> ```

The general rule is, in arithmetic operations within `((...))` you don't need to use the dollars in variable names.

#### Don't use backticks

Instead of this:

> ```
> commonMultiple=`expr $1 \* $2`
> ```

This is the recommended writing style for sub shells:

```
commonMultiple=$(expr $1 \* $2)
```

#### Don't use `expr`

It's better to avoid `expr`, and you can do the same thing easier using Bash arithmetics, for example:

```
((commonMultiple = $1 * $2))
```

The for loops can be simplified similarly, instead of:

```
for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$1 )); do
    sumArg1=`expr $sumArg1 + $i`
done
```

You can write:

```
for (( i = 0; i <= limit; i+=$1 )); do
    ((sumArg1 += i))
done
```

Apply the same thing everywhere.

Comment: Trying that out and posting back results thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

### Consider `seq`

Using seq makes your code significantly shorter in those for loops since you can just rely on seq to do your limit checking and the increments.
beware that seq is non-standard though.

> ```
> for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$1 )); do
> ```

could simply be written as:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $i $limit) do
```

<sub>thanks to janos for pointing out the grievous flaws in the previous version of my answer</sub>

### To Space or not to space?

Compare your spacing in that for loop header:

> ```
> for (( i = 0; i <= $limit; i+=$1 )); do
> ```

stick to either always adding spaces around operators or not doing it at all. I recommend the former. This makes for a significant readability improvement, especially when not having syntax highlighting or similar.

I'm sure there's more, but that's about the whole extent of my bash knowledge, so I leave the rest in the hands of more competent reviewers :)

Comment: `seq` does look a hell of a lot better! Thanks a lot for your answer. Everything I read about my own code is an eye opener at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the loop improvements proposed in [@Vogel612's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112808/52802) you may check in the beginning of the script if the script arguments are numbers actually.

`expr` will give unexpected results or errors otherwise.

You can do so as proposed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash) from Stack Overflow:

> ```
> re='^[0-9]+$'
> if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] || ! [[ $2 =~ $re ]]; then
>     echo "error: Please provide 2 numeric parameters" >&2; exit 1
> fi
> ```

Comment: It's gonna take a while for me to understand that snippet, but the idea is more than appropriate!

Comment: @FaustoNA It's well explained in the linked Q&A, that's a check based on regular expressions. Glad to help.